# Send File To Microsoft Xps Document Writer

Tags: document, send, xps, writer

Please Read This Article . http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

this Article Send File & String To Printer With Binary Format.
But One Problem . Can Not Create File XPS Or Save XPS File From "Microsoft XPs Document Writer" Printer . 
If seting di.OutPutFile Equal File Address ("D:\test.xps") . Create File But File is **ill** And XPS Viewer Not Open File.

what is Problem ?  Please help Me!.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25376/Introduction-to-XPS-Part-1-of-n-of-too-many) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305%28office.12%29.aspx) for pdf/word. You can also use [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7), like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2008/09/24/convert-office-documents-docx-pptx-pub-into-pdf-programmatically.aspx)

Comment: Please Help For Convert PDF To Xps OR PNG With Out Third Party Compunent.